# Magento 2 - Scheduled changes of block is not reflecting in the front end side

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am trying to scheduled the block content changes in the blocks. After the scheduled time, it was executed successfully and the content was reflected on the block content section in MBO side. But the problem is the content was not reflected in the front end side.

But if i do clear cache or save the content -> block then the changes are reflected in the front end side. without doing these, is there any other option to display the content changes in the front end side after the schedule new update time?

Magento version - 2.4.2-p1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have worked with Magento but I think you partially answered your own question. Magento (Adobe Commerce) is designed with a lot of [automatic caching built-in](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/clear-directories/). When you manually cleared the cache in the dashboard, this triggered the process that rebuilds the block and adds it back into the cache.

If you look at the [How to Clear the Directories](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/clear-directories/#how-to-clear-the-directories) section I believe you need the last option:

```bash
magento cache:clean {type}
```

The [Manage the Cache](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/manage-cache.html) page in the online handbook covers all the additional commands you can use. There is also a chance you may need to run the [Code Compiler](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/code-compiler.html) as well, but keep in mind I haven't used the newest version of Magento, this may have been a requirement of the specific site I was managing at the time.

In either case, you can setup a cron job on your server to periodically run the command(s) to clear your sites cache(s). I suspect you may not have cron properly setup already, since a lot of these tasks are automatically handled by Magento's crontab. I would double check that Magento's cron jobs are [configured and running](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/configure-cron-jobs.html) first; maybe you just need to increase how often it runs? If that still fails, you should setup your own cron to clear the cache periodically at a time that is safe for your site.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue with Magento 2.4.2-p1.

You may need to remove the pub/static/frontend folder and run the deploy command to reflect the changes on the front end.

Alternatively, you may need to override the file in your theme and flush the cache after applying changes.

I hope this helps.